# How to overcome lag in display in showing Toast every second

Tags: android

My Toast isn't sync with Timer seconds, how to overcome lag in display

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disabling Password, Please wait : " + millisUntilFinished/1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFinish() {
                                            Log.d("Admin", "Disabling Password");
                                            devicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality(demoDeviceAdmin,DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED);
                                            devicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength(demoDeviceAdmin, 0);
                                            boolean resulttwo = devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
                                            Log.d("Admin", "Disabling Password : " + resulttwo);
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congratulations!! Password Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                }.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toast provides a cancel method,

Define mToast as data member and initialize to null

```
 CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (mToast != null) {
                mToast.cancel();
            }
            mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disabling Password, Please wait : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.show();
            Log.d("Admin", "Disabling Password, Please wait : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("Admin", "Disabling Password");
            devicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality(demoDeviceAdmin,DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED);
            devicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength(demoDeviceAdmin, 0);
             boolean resulttwo = devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
            Log.d("Admin", "Disabling Password : ");
            if (mToast != null) {
                mToast.cancel();
            }
            mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congratulations!! Password Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.show();
        }
    }.start();
```